# What power supply should be used for the B+ model?

Tags: power-supply, power, pi-models

I'm thinking about purchasing a Raspberry Pi B+ model, and the Raspberry Pi website states that the power supply should output 2 A through a micro- USB supply.

OK, but in terms of voltage, what should it be? Is 5 V suitable? That's what many of the [Amazon devices for 2A](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pixnor-Portable-UK-plug-Adapter-Charger-2014Black1/dp/B00IVE2NUC/) seem to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The power supply should support 5 V. It has not changed (from model B to B+), and it is the default for the micro-USB output.

[FAQ: What are the power requirements?](http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/faqs/#powerReqs)

> The device is powered by 5 V micro-USB.

The provided output current should range between 700 mA to 2000 mA (2.0 A) depending on the current drain of your plugged-in USB devices.

This holds for every model and revision (A, A+, B, and B+). The Model A needs a bit less current compared to the Model B (about 200 mA) and both `+`Models (A+, B+) need a bit less current compared to the older versions.

Comment: I have just purchased a B+ model and the instructions say its power supply should provide a maximum of 2000mA. The power supply I've got provides 2100mA. Do I understand it correctly that this won't damage my Raspberry Pi? If it produces more heat, can I still put it in a case or will there be a risk of overheating?

Comment: @Giorgio it means your power supply can deliver up to 2100mA, it doesn't mean your power supply will deliver only 2100mA. Actually your device will need some power maybe only 500mA and the power supply will only deliver that. Mine are 5V and up to 2400mA but most of the time it's using between 700-1300mA.

Comment: @Huygens: Thanks. Meanwhile I have been using my Raspberry Pi, mostly as a git server, for months and it has never had a problem.

Answer (score 4):

The B+ should be powered by 5 V at 2 A. I have the official [PSU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_supply_unit_%28computer%29), and it is rated at that and runs my Raspberry Pi B+ perfectly.

Comment: No worries im running the b+ off 5v 2a and it works a treat.