# What is the best power supply for the Raspberry Pi B+?

Tags: power-supply

I have read through the question *[What power supply should be used for the B+ model?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/22415)* to find the best power supply for the B+. I have read that if you are connecting additional things to the Raspberry Pi, 1.5 A may not be enough.

What reliable power supply can be recommended to buy (preferably 2 A as per the reason above, and 5 V as recommended in multiple sources)? [A power supply on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LSEOTYK) advertises 2 A, but it actually delivers 1.5 A only, as seen by some rather dissatisfied reviewers.

Is there a link or two for where to buy a good power supply for the B+ model?

Answer (score 3):

I can thoroughly recommend [the power supplies provided by The Pi Hut](http://thepihut.com/collections/raspberry-pi-power-supplies) in the UK. They deliver a steady 2A supply and are of very high quality.

Comment: Agree. I found the Northpole ones on Amazon decent but one seemed to be flakey (corrupting SD cards), the PiHut is rock solid and good value at 5 GBP.

Answer (score 2):

[This one](https://www.adafruit.com/products/501) is clearly one of the best I could find. It's **5.25 V** to compensate for the resistance of the cable and is quite practical since it has no cable, but a USB connector that allows you to connect virtually any USB cable you may have, with different output connector.

Comment: I've had good results with this too - powering a pi, keyboard, and MyPassport USB drive, for instance. Quite possible that was somewhat 'out of spec' on the USB power but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are looking for. Recently I read this research, which was very informative for me. If you need high quality audio, I recommend reading this information:

http://www.lygte-info.dk/info/usbPowerSupplyTest%20UK.html

This is not to suggest which models should be promoted, but rather to give an idea what kind of specifications are relevant for a power supply, given a certain application or requirement.